Application forgets current View Controller and tableview after alert controller tapped in Swift
I am running into issues where my app seems to forget the current View Controller and its properties--namely a tableView--after launching an AlertController with Action methods.
For example, after presenting an alert with a button action, tapping the button leads to a crash when the function references the tableview on the screen which it says is nil.
The VC in question is embedded in a navigation controller and launched modally from a VC that is part of a UITabBarController
So the stack should be someething like UITabBarController -> UINavigationController -> ViewControllerOnScreen -> AlertController
I solved a previous issue where the VC was disappearing from the stack (though still on screen_) after tapping a UIGesture Recognizer with the following method:
func topVC() -> UIViewController {
        var topController: UIViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!
        while (topController.presentedViewController != nil) {
            topController =  topController.presentedViewController!
        }
        return topController
    }

In that case, I just needed to launch the alert. The topVC in the prior method was the ViewController on screen and it launched the alert successfully.
However, now it is the tableView on screen that is nil.  The tableView is a property of the VC and it is declared as an IBOutlet
@IBOutlet var tableView : UITableView!

In this case, however, when I call the topVC method above, topVC is the navigationController not the VC on screen and so it does not have a tableView property.
Is there a way to reference the VC I want (the one on screen) from the navigationController?
Would greatly appreciate any suggestions.
Edit:
As suggested by Karmen, there are a lot of answers in the link provided.
I pieced them together as follows but still not getting the actual VC that contains properties. I am just getting the UINavigationController:
extension UIWindow {
        func visibleController() -> UIViewController? {
            var top = self.rootViewController
            while true {
                if let presented = top?.presentedViewController {
                    top = presented
                } else if let nav = top as? UINavigationController {
                    top = nav.visibleViewController
                } else if let tab = top as? UITabBarController {
                    top = tab.selectedViewController
                } else {
                    break
                }
            }
            return top
        }
    }

Since I have an alertController present , I suspect there is some issue with the key window. This answer in Objective-C from the link addresses the keyWindow issue with an alertController but am struggling to translate into Swift:
-(UIWindow *) returnWindowWithWindowLevelNormal
{
    NSArray *windows = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows;
    for(UIWindow *topWindow in windows)
    {
        if (topWindow.windowLevel == UIWindowLevelNormal)
            return topWindow;
    }
    return [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
}

-(UIViewController *) getTopMostController
{
    UIWindow *topWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    if (topWindow.windowLevel != UIWindowLevelNormal)
    {
        topWindow = [self returnWindowWithWindowLevelNormal];
    }

    UIViewController *topController = topWindow.rootViewController;
    if(topController == nil)
    {
        topWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window;
        if (topWindow.windowLevel != UIWindowLevelNormal)
        {
            topWindow = [self returnWindowWithWindowLevelNormal];
        }
        topController = topWindow.rootViewController;
    }

    while(topController.presentedViewController)
    {
        topController = topController.presentedViewController;
    }

    if([topController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
    {
        UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController*)topController;
        topController = [nav.viewControllers lastObject];

        while(topController.presentedViewController)
        {
            topController = topController.presentedViewController;
        }
    }

    return topController;
}


Have you already checked all the solutions in the How to find topmost viewController. Especially the swift ones?

I tried the swift ones and none workedI suspect it is the alert window that is messing things up by changing the key window and that is only mentioned in one written in objective-c so I'm struggling with that one

I am suspecting that I don't actually want the top view controller as it has been lost somehow. I want the viewcontroller embedded in the navigation controller

@user6631314 - what is you program logic like, that you need to present from the "top most" controller, instead of presenting it from the current controller?

The logic is I have a chat interface that uses a tableView which can produce images. The user can swipe to share or save the image already. That works fine using a swipe action on tableview. However, I want to add the ability to tap on the image to bring up an action sheet to share or save. Adding the gestureRecognizer to the imagetap initially caused a problem where I could not present the alert ecause the view controller was nil. I solved this by finding the topVC which let me fire the alert.

The problem now is that when user taps action method in alert, the TableView  for chat is nil.  The tableView is a property of the chat VC. So the crux of the matter is how do I find that chat view controller which seems to have fallen off the navigation stack to access that tableView that has also fallen off. The topMost View controller is now the navigationController in which the VC with the tableView is embedded but I don't know how to get the viewcontroller from the navigation controller.

@user6631314 - I really think you're going down the wrong path with trying to "get the top vc" approach. "Adding the gestureRecognizer to the imagetap initially caused a problem where I could not present the alert because the view controller was nil" ... that should be a straightforward issue to solve.

This doesn't answer your question about "finding the top VC" - because I really think that's not the approach you want to use.
Instead, let's look at adding a Closure to the cell class so our Controller can "do something" when a cell's image is tapped.
First, we add a property to the cell class that looks like this:
class MyTestCell: UITableViewCell {

    var imgTapClosure: ((UITableViewCell) -> ())?

Then, also in the cell class, in our func that handles the Tap Gesture:
@objc func handleTap(_ g: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // call the Closure to inform the controller of the tap
    imgTapClosure?(self)
}

In our controller's cellForRowAt func, we can "set" that closure:
    // set the closure
    cell.imgTapClosure = { [weak self] theCell in
        guard let self = self,
              let idxPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: theCell)
        else { return }
        
        // now we know which cell got the tap on the image, and
        //  we can "do something" with that information
        self.doSomething(indexPath: idxPath)
    }

Now, in that same controller, we can write a doSomething() func to, for example, present a UIAlertController.
This will work if the controller with the table view is the "root" controller, or if it's in a navigation stack, or if it's in a Tab Controller, or if it's in a navigation stack in a Tab Controller.
Here is a complete example...

Simple data struct - "lastAction" will be set by the Alert Controller
struct MyTestObject {
    var title: String = ""
    var imgName: String = ""
    var lastAction: String = ""
}


Cell class - with Closure
class MyTestCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    var imgTapClosure: ((UITableViewCell) -> ())?
    
    var titleLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    var lastActionLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    var theImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier);
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        
        // for this example, we're going to use SF Symbol images
        //  which do some weird things with framing
        // so let's embed it in a view
        let cView = UIView()
        cView.addSubview(theImageView)
        
        contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(lastActionLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(cView)

        titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        lastActionLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        theImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        
        // avoid auto-layout complaints
        let b = cView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        b.priority = .required - 1
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            lastActionLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            lastActionLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            cView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            cView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            b,
            
            cView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0),
            cView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0),

            theImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0),
            theImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0),
            theImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cView.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cView.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0),

        ])
        
        // element properties
        theImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        theImageView.tintColor = .systemRed

        // add tap gesture
        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
        theImageView.addGestureRecognizer(t)
        theImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        // so we can see the framing
        titleLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        lastActionLabel.backgroundColor = .init(red: 0.9, green: 0.95, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        theImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        cView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        
    }
    
    @objc func handleTap(_ g: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // call the Closure to inform the controller of the tap
        imgTapClosure?(self)
    }
    
}


View Controller class - with table view as subview... when the imageView in a cell is tapped, we will present an Alert Controller with a few options.
class MyTestViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    var theData: [MyTestObject] = []

    // if you have set this up in Storyboard
    //@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    
    // for this example, we'll add the table view via code
    let tableView = UITableView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        self.title = "Activities"
        
        // create some sample data, using a bunch of
        //  SF Symbol names from the "Fitness" category
        let imgNames: [String] = [
            "figure.american.football",
            "figure.archery",
            "figure.australian.football",
            "figure.badminton",
            "figure.barre",
            "figure.baseball",
            "figure.basketball",
            "figure.bowling",
            "figure.boxing",
            "figure.climbing",
            "figure.cooldown",
            "figure.core.training",
            "figure.cricket",
            "figure.skiing.crosscountry",
            "figure.cross.training",
            "figure.curling",
            "figure.dance",
            "figure.disc.sports",
            "figure.skiing.downhill",
            "figure.elliptical",
            "figure.equestrian.sports",
            "figure.fencing",
        ]
        for (i, str) in imgNames.enumerated() {
            let obj = MyTestObject(title: "Row \(i)", imgName: str)
            theData.append(obj)
        }

        // if you're using an @IBOutlet table view, the following is not needed
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])
        
        tableView.register(MyTestCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "c")
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return theData.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "c", for: indexPath) as! MyTestCell
        let d = theData[indexPath.row]
        cell.titleLabel.text = d.title
        cell.lastActionLabel.text = "Last Action: " + d.lastAction
        if let img = UIImage(systemName: d.imgName) {
            cell.theImageView.image = img
        }
        
        // set the closure
        cell.imgTapClosure = { [weak self] theCell in
            guard let self = self,
                  let idxPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: theCell)
            else { return }
            
            // now we know which cell got the tap on the image, and
            //  we can "do something" with that information
            self.doSomething(indexPath: idxPath)
        }
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func doSomething(indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        // use preferredStyle: .actionSheet or .alert as desired
        //let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "My Title", message: "What do you want to do?", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "My Title", message: "What do you want to do?", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save the image", style: .default, handler: { (alertAction: UIAlertAction) in
            // add code to Save the image
            //  for this example, let's just update the action and reload the row
            self.theData[indexPath.row].lastAction = "Save!"
            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }))
        
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Share the image", style: .default, handler: { (alertAction: UIAlertAction) in
            // add code to Share the image
            //  for this example, let's just update the action and reload the row
            self.theData[indexPath.row].lastAction = "Share!"
            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }))
        
        // only if we are in a navigationController stack,
        //  add a "Show" action
        if let navVC = self.navigationController {
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Show the image", style: .default, handler: { (alertAction: UIAlertAction) in
                // for this example, update the action and reload the row
                self.theData[indexPath.row].lastAction = "Show!"
                self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
                // then push to a new VC to show the image
                let vc = ShowImageVC()
                vc.theImageName = self.theData[indexPath.row].imgName
                navVC.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            }))
        }
        
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (alertAction: UIAlertAction) in
            // user selected Cancel, so
            //  for this example, let's just update the action and reload the row
            self.theData[indexPath.row].lastAction = "Cancelled"
            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }))
        
        present(alertController, animated: true)
    }
}


"Show Image" View Controller class - if running in a navigation controller, we'll have an option to "Show" the image, which will instantiate and Push this controller.
class ShowImageVC: UIViewController {
    
    var theImageName: String = ""
    
    let imgView = UIImageView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        self.title = "Show Image"
        
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(imgView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            imgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
        ])
        
        imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imgView.tintColor = .systemRed
        if let img = UIImage(systemName: theImageName) {
            imgView.image = img
        }
    }
    
}


Some screen-caps, showing the above code running in a controller in a navigation stack, in a tab view controller...
On first load:

Tap the image in cell row 2:

Select "Save" - we update our data and reload the row (actual code would save the image):

Tap the image in cell row 3, Select "Share" - we update our data and reload the row (actual code would share the image):

Tap the image in cell row 4, Select "Cancel" - we update our data and reload the row:

Tap the image in cell row 5, Select "Show" - we update our data and reload the row, and push to a new VC:

Back from Show:

If desired, we can set the Alert Controller to preferredStyle: .actionSheet instead of .alert:

